# Comparing second order statistic of n draws and first order statistic of n-1 draws

Tags: probability, order-statistics

Let $x^{(i),n}$ be the $i$-th order statistic of $n$ draws from some distribution function $F$ on $[0,1]$.

I have a claim that
$$\mathbb{E}[\max \{ x^{(2),n}, m\}] < \mathbb{E}[\max \{ x^{(1),n-1}, m\}]. $$
I was not able to prove this for general distributions yet.

Does someone have a counterexample? A cdf $F$ where the inequality does not hold?

\begin{align}
\int_m^1 x n (n-1) F(x)^{n-2} (1-F(x)) f(x) dx + n F(m)^{n-1} (1-F(m))m > \\
\int_m^1 x (n-1) F(x)^{n-2} f(x) dx +  F(m)^{n-1} m
\end{align}

Comment: To clarify: By $i$-th order statistic, I mean the $i$-th largest value! Not the smallest.

And an intuition for why this should hold:
Take $(n-1)$ draws and let $\alpha$ be the highest of the values.
Then take another draw, call the value $\beta$. Either the $n$-th draw is $\beta \geq \alpha$.
Then the second highest value of the $n$ draws is equal to the highest of the $(n-1)$ draws, $= \alpha$.
Or $\beta < \alpha$ and then the second highest value of the $n$ draws is weakly less than the highest of the $(n-1)$ draws.

Comment: Anything unclear?

Comment: The *opposite* inequality holds since $x^n_{(2)}\geqslant x^{n-1}_{(1)}$ stochastically (and yes the inequality is strict for every $m$ smaller than the supremum of the support of the underlying distribution).

Comment: *That is, the inequality is strict for every m so-and-so unless the distribution F is Dirac.

Comment: @Did That is not true. At least not with the (maybe confusing) notation I clarified above (depending on who you talk to, order stat means $i$th highest or lowest value). Take $n=2$, $m=0$, the expectation of the minimum of two draws (=E[$x_{(2)}^2]$) is clearly smaller than the expectation of a single draw.
Take $n=2$, $m=1/2$ and uniform distribution. $5/12 < 5/8$.
My question is why can't I see this intuition directly in the integral? It should be the same as your intuition but reversed as I think you had a reversed notation in mind.
Sorry for all the edits and the confusion.

Comment: Only $x^2_{(2)}$ is the **maximum** of two draws. If you wish to depart from established notations, please say so. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Comment: That's why I said so in the first comment. I have seen both notations.
Thank you and I am sorry.